# Keyboard must be unplugged and replugged in after startup?

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard

I recently bought a new keyboard for my Windows 7 desktop.  After turning on the system, the keyboard will refuse to work, and it seems like nothing on it works.  But after unplugging the keyboard out of the USB socket, and replugging it back in it will work perfectly fine.

I have had to do this since Day 1, and every time I boot up the machine it exhibits the exact same symptoms I listed above.

Why is it doing this?

The keyboard is an HP SK-2025.

Comment: My guess would be you need a new(or updated) driver for the keyboard/USB.

Comment: What make/model of keyboard is this?

Comment: HP SK-2025 keyboard

Comment: @cliff2310 But I have not installed any drivers, I simply plugged in the keyboard, and it self-installed.

Comment: @cyberweb poweruser Right click on 'My Computer' and select 'manage' then 'Device Manager'.  Look under the USB heading, right click and look for 'update software driver. Or go the keyboard brand website and look for a new driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, in Windows 7, even when unable to find device drivers for the keyboard HP SK-2025, the issue was still there.

I upgraded to Windows 10, after I was able to log in for the first time I never had the issue again. Perhaps Windows 10 had automatically found a driver for it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens in windows 7 when there's multiple driver installed for a specific device. you have to delete them manually and that would fix the issue. But since you upgraded.. I guess the problem is solved..